# How to call a API in CAKE PHP?

Tags: php, api, curl, smtp, file-get-contents

I have seen many answer in stack overflow about this. But Nothing is working. I am trying to send a mail using SMTP server. But the server is dynamic. For me this is not a problem, but for sending mail I am try to make an api. For call the API I did the below code.

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    //echo $url; die;
    $ch = curl_init();

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
$data_ar = array(
   "email_ip" => $SmtpServer,
   "username" =>$SmtpUser,
   "password" => $SmtpPass,
   "port" => $SmtpPort,
   "email_id" => 'admin@owntheblog.com',
   "email_to" =>  $_POST['to'],
   "email_subject" => $_POST['sub'],
   "email_content" => $_POST['message']
     );
    $data_js = json_encode($data_ar);
    $url='http://setup.spotrix.com/app/webroot/mail/mail.php?smtp='.$data_js;
    $response = curl_get_contents($url);
```

or replace the last line with `$response = file_get_contents($url);`

I found the above code in the stackoverflow. But in the both the case (as in the CURL or file_get_contents) the API calling is not working. But if you directly hit the URL in the browser then the mail is working. Like the URL is,

```
http://setup.spotrix.com/app/webroot/mail/mail.php?smtp={%22email_ip%22:%22IP%22,%22username%22:%22username%22,%22password%22:%22password%22,%22port%22:port,%22email_id%22:%22form_email%22,%22email_to%22:%22to_email%22,%22email_subject%22:%22Test%20Subject%22,%22email_content%22:%22Test%20Message%22}
```

Then the mail is working. But not working in the code. I am using cakephp 2.X. I think I made a mistake here. Please help me to solve this problem.
I made a form in php for test the mail portion. I am sharing the code also.

```
<?php
//Server Address
$SmtpServer= 'Your SMTP IP';
$SmtpPort= YOUR SMTP PORT; //default
$SmtpUser='YOUR SMTP USER NAME';
$SmtpPass='YOUR SMTP PASSWORD';
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
 $data_ar = array(
   "email_ip" => $SmtpServer,
   "username" =>$SmtpUser,
   "password" => $SmtpPass,
   "port" => $SmtpPort,
   "email_id" => $_POST['from'],
   "email_to" =>  $_POST['to'],
   "email_subject" => $_POST['sub'],
   "email_content" => $_POST['message']
     );
    $data_js = json_encode($data_ar);
    $url='http://setup.spotrix.com/app/webroot/mail/mail.php?smtp='.$data_js;
    $response = curl_get_contents($url);
    //$response = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $response;
die;
}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Test Mail</title>
</head>

 <body>
 <form method="post" action="">
 <table width="500px">
 <tr><td width="20%">To : </td>
 <td ><input type="text" name="to" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>From :</td><td><input type='text' name="from" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Subject :</td><td><input type='text' name="sub" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Message :</td><td><textarea name="message"></textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value=" Send " /></td></tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

You can copy paste the above code and change to your SMTP details and use the mail system. You can echo the `$url` to see the requested url. Try to copy paste the url in the browser see the mail is working but not from the code. If the mail send successfully then it will reture 1 else 0. Please make me correct id I make any mistake.

Thanks in advance for help.